# Waiting for a GWT Composite visualization

Tags: gwt, loading, composite

I am creating a Composite (various panels with my application 'areas') on-the-fly, when the user clicks on a menu entry, and visualizing it on my central panel in the screen.

However, some Composites takes a little more loading, how can I be aware of the 'start-loading' and 'finished-loading' events? I mean, can I display a spinner/waiter before creating the new panel and hide it after the creation?

What's the best practice?

---

I think I'll try LAZYPANEL. Maybe it could help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Display the loading image by default
Override the onLoad(). Inside the onload initialize and build the composite. Just before adding all the children to the composite, call clear() to remove the loading image.

Comment: I use uiBinder, so I already make all the work in my Widget(composite) constructor: uiBinder creates and bind all my objects. Finally I call initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this)); So do I have to move my initialization code in the onLoad? Explain better please

Comment: Sorry I don't use UI binder as I prefer to hand code. So won't be able to help you on that part.
Just move the rest of the code from your constructor to the onLoad(). Remember to call clear() before adding any widgets to remove the loading image.

Comment: maneesh... I only wanted to have something like a "beforeLoadWidget()" method where I could display a "wait please" somewhere. Then I do setWidget() on my simplepanel, the a callback "afterWidgetIsLoaded()" how can I do?